# javascript if statement failing with ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

on my backend in nodejs, I am basically saying, once the users logs in, set `req.session.loggedin = true`. once it is true, and the user renders the protected page (wholesale pricing page), then set the variable `wholesalelogin = true`, all working at this point. so now, on my front end, I am now doing this:

```
<script>
          if ('<%= wholesaleuser %>' == true) {
              console.log("wholesale user is" + '<%= wholesaleuser %>')
              document.write(' <p>Price: <em>$<%= data[i].WHOLESALE_PRICE %></em>')
          } else {
            console.log("wholesale user is not" + '<%= wholesaleuser %>')
            document.write('<p>Price: <em>$<%= data[i].RETAIL_PRICE %></em>')
          }
      </script>
```

when I log it (in the console.log), it is returning the value true, which is good, but the problem is, It Is not doing `document.write(' <p>Price: <em>$<%= data[i].WHOLESALE_PRICE %></em>')`, but instead doing the retail price one, although the result is true.  so I assume now my if statement is not working. what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, if you output the `wholesaleuser` variable surrounded with apostrophes, you end up with comparing string to boolean `'true' == true` which evaluates to false

```js
console.log('true' == true);
```

IMHO, you can simplify this condition to the following form

```js
if (<%= wholesaleuser %>) {
```

and it should solve your issue, under the assumption that the variable `wholesaleuser` is always defined and is of type boolean.